# How can I cut a variable in a for loop each time differently?

Tags: python, for-loop, split

I have a document called 'asin.txt':

```
in,Huawei1,DE.FR.IT.UK
out,Huawei2,DE.FR.IT
out,Huawei3,FR
in,Huawei4,FR.IT
in,Huawei5,IT
```

I'm opening this file and make an OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
reader = csv.reader(open('asin.txt','r'),delimiter=',')
reader1 = csv.reader(open('asin.txt','r'),delimiter=',')
d = OrderedDict((row[0], row[1].strip()) for row in reader)
d1 = OrderedDict((row[1], row[2].strip()) for row in reader1)
```

Than i create a 'for' loop:

```
from itertools import izip
for (a, b), (c, e) in izip(d.items(), d1.items()):
    """in the first time: a='in'; b='Huawei1'; c='Huawei1'; e='DE.FR.IT.UK'"""
    c1, c2, c3, c4 = c.split('.') # i'm cutting variable 'c'
    try:
       ...........
```

But than a Python give me an error:

```
 c1, c2, c3, c4 = c.split('.')
 ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack
```

I know why i have an error, because in the first line of the 'asin.txt':

```
in,Huawei1,DE.FR.IT.UK
```

after second coma i have 4 countries and , but in the second line of the 'asin.txt'

```
out,Huawei2,DE.FR.IT
```

after second coma i have 3 countries. And i have this statement `c1, c2, c3, c4 = c.split('.')` .

How can i make the program that cuts **c** each time on exactly pieces as countries in the asin.txt?

So for exemple in a first lap it cuts on 4 pieces on second on 3 pieces on third on 1 piece....

Comment: You don't - look at the responses to your previous question. Don't try and name them all if you don't need to. Just keep them as a list... `countries = c.split('.')`...

Comment: what are you doing with c1, c2, c3?

Comment: As well, in the majority of cases if you're numbering variables (c1, c2, c3 or s1, s2, s3) chances are you're doing something wrong, or in such a way that can't be maintained easily. In these cases consider using a list or doing it another way.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the results of `split` as a list:

```
cList = c.split('.')
```

This way, `c` is always "cut" into the same number of pieces as countries in asin.txt.

Comment: Actually just doing a `c = c.split('.')` would convert `c` into a list of the necessary size in-place.